# Test method with default access modifier (wildfly and arquillian)

Tags: java, integration-testing, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to test a method with default visibility. The tests and the method's class are in the same package, if I change the access modifier to `public`, it works.
I checked my generated war file to be sure about the packages names, and the both are in the same.

**Exception:**

```
org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.ArquillianProxyException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException : Class org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections can not access a member of class mypackage.CertificateService with modifiers "" [Proxied because : Original exception caused: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException]
```

So, my **service** method is like that:

```
// CertificateService
@Inject
private CertificateRepository repository;

CertificateDTO createOrUpdate(final CertificateDTO dto, LocalDate date) {
    repository.createOrUpdate(dto,date);
}
```

And in my **IT** class:

```
// CertificateServiceIT

@Inject
private CertificateRepository repository;

@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    return Deployments.createWarDeployment(CertificateServiceIT.class.getSimpleName());
}

@Test (expected = BusinessException.class)
@Transactional(TransactionMode.ROLLBACK)
public void CertificateServiceITTest001() throws Exception {

    ...

    repository.createOrUpdate(dto, localdate);

}
```

And the class **Deployments**:

```
public static WebArchive createWarDeployment(final String packageId) {
    final WebArchive war = DeploymentUtil.createWarDeployment(packageId,
            "myPackage:model",
            "myPackage:my-commons-keycloak");

    final File modelJar = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
            .resolve("myPackage:model")
            .withoutTransitivity().asSingle(File.class);

    final JavaArchive modelArchive = ShrinkWrap.create(ZipImporter.class, "model.jar")
            .importFrom(modelJar).as(JavaArchive.class);
    modelArchive.delete("META-INF/persistence.xml");

    return war.addPackages(true, "myPackage.business")
            .addPackages(true, "myPackage.api")
            .addAsLibraries(modelArchive)
            .addAsWebInfResource("jboss-deployment-structure.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource("META-INF/ejb-jar.xml", "ejb-jar.xml")
            .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsResource("Messages.properties")
            .addAsResource("META-INF/beans.xml")
            .addAsResource("certificate01.p12")
            .addAsResource("certificate02.pfx");
}
```

Both classes (**CertificateService** and **CertificateServiceIT**) are deployed in the same package.

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you think that the problem is with access modifier ? What error did you get ?

Comment: Why are your tests not in the same package as the thing you're testing?

Comment: I edited the post with the log error, both classes are in the same package.

Comment: Are you attempting to use this bean with CDI?

Comment: Please add a code sample of what is failing.

Comment: ok guys, I just updated the post with the code usage.